# How to login to Google Calendar without OAuth2?

Tags: vb.net, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

**SUMMARY**

I have a Vb.net application (Windows form) and I need to manage google calendar for any of software user. I thought of having the user access directly from the program and not authenticate himself for every operation on the calendar
I tried OAuth2 method but is not user friendly. I must login directly from the app and without json files.

**WHAT I TRIED**

I'm developing software with integrated Google Calendar.
I'm not a Google API expert, so by searching a bit on the web, I managed to authenticate using the credentials.json file that directly creates Google.
At the moment, the software works like this: I press the "Login" button; automatically opens the Google login page in the browser; I enter email and password on the official Google login page; I access; I manually close the browser page; I go back to the program where a msgbox warns me of successful authentication.

```
Public scopes As IList(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
Public service As CalendarService

Function LoginGoogle()

    scopes.Add(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar)

    Dim credential As UserCredential

    If Directory.Exists("C:\credentials") Then

        Try

            Directory.Delete("c:\credentials", True)

        Catch

            MsgBox("Error! Can't delete folder 'credentials'")

        End Try

        Using stream As New FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read) 
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None,
                        New FileDataStore("c:\credentials")).Result
        End Using

        Dim initializer As New BaseClientService.Initializer()
        initializer.HttpClientInitializer = credential
        initializer.ApplicationName = "Carpedia"   ' app's name
        service = New CalendarService(initializer)
        Return 0

    Else

        Using stream As New FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read) 
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None,
                        New FileDataStore("c:\credentials")).Result
        End Using

        Dim initializer As New BaseClientService.Initializer()
        initializer.HttpClientInitializer = credential
        initializer.ApplicationName = "Carpedia"   ' app's name
        service = New CalendarService(initializer)
        Return 0

    End If


End Function
```

**WHAT I WOULD LIKE**

I would like to create a form where to enter email and password; click on the login button; log in automatically without using the browser.

Example: https://youtu.be/FW9_gCD8vVg?t=15 (minute 0:18)

How can I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: who is the owner of the calendar you want to access - you or your users?

Comment: Each user has his own personal calendar

Comment: `I thought of having the user access directly from the program and not authenticate himself for every operation on the calendar I tried OAuth2 method but is not user friendly. I must login directly from the app`, any secure aware user wouldn't ***support this***, why would a user enter their credentials to some random form to authenticate them when Google does this? Acutally, this would be in violation of Google's API Terms of Service if you implemented it.

Comment: I did not like the idea of ​​having to switch from the browser for authentication, but as you say I would have violated the terms of privacy, and in any case you can not do what I wanted so I will continue to use the OAuth2 method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging in with username and password though your application is called client login.  This was shut down by google in 2015.

In order to access user data you must have the permission of the user to do this.  The only way for you to get the permission of the user is to use OAuth2.  There is no other option for you to do this.   As you can see the google calendar api documentation mentions only [oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54289476/1841839) for accessing private user data.

You appear to already be using the Google APIs .net client library which is the best way i know of to authenticate a user in a windows application.

Comment: I understood. Thanks a lot! Is it possible, however, to integrate the browser in the application to login without opening it externally?

Comment: No that probably won't work you need to open the authorization page in the os webbrowser.

Comment: Ok, I understood. Thank you!